# Prove me existence of ghosts

Tags: ghosts, evidence

Can anyone give the proof (spiritual, philosphocal and scientific) for existence of ghosts? As many scriptures  talk about them but I think it's prakshipt.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't a prakshipt , rather  it can be said that , *it isnt tangible for a normal human perception, to grasp the existence of other beings in this universe*. Perhaps , an evidence could be sought by deductive reasoning, whenever a direct proof is not possible.. that is to say , Although a human can't perceive supersonic frequencies,it is inferred by  principle of  galtons whistle that  such frequencies exist, also beings such as dogs do perceive them..

One who has got a deeper insight of Prana and Akasha can know the other beings. science behind this phenomenon is clearly explained in Raja yoga [Prana](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/raja-yoga/prana.htm) ,  by Swami Vivekananda

> We have five senses, and we represent Prana in a certain state of vibration. All beings in the same state of vibration will see one another, but if there are beings who represent Prana in a higher state of vibration, they will not be seen......Suppose this room is full of beings whom we do not see. They represent Prana in a certain state of vibration while we represent another. Suppose they represent a quick one, and we the opposite. Prana is the material of which they are composed, as well as we. All are parts of the same ocean of Prana, they differ only in their rate of vibration. If I can bring myself to the quick vibration, this plane will immediately change for me: I shall not see you any more; you vanish and they appear. Some of you, perhaps, know this to be true. All this bringing of the mind into a higher state of vibration is included in one word in Yoga — Samadhi. and the lower states of Samadhi give us visions of these beings. The highest grade of Samadhi is when we see the real thing.
> **Swami Vivekananda, Raja Yoga** , [Prana](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/raja-yoga/prana.htm)

Comment: How to get deep insight of prana and akasha??

Comment: @Hope, The knowledge and control of this Prana is really what is meant by Pranayama.The idea can be known from commentaries on yoga sutras.Raja yoga is a great book on the subject